# Using a dictionary with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

All,

I am still new to ko so I am bit confused with what I need to do.

My dictionary contains the following keys :

'Group 1' which contains the following objects
{ location: 'Orlando', date: '07/10/2018'},
{ location: 'Miami', date: '08/22/2018'}

'Group 2' which contains the following object
{ location: 'Tampa', date: '09/10/2018'},

I am trying to use the key as a label with a button below it for each location and the hover over as the date (example below) :

Group 1
|button that says Orlando with hover over date|
|button that says Miami with hover over date|

Group 2
|button that says Tampa with hover over date|

```
const dictionary = {
  "Group 1": [
    { location: "Orlando", date: "07/10/2018" },
    { location: "Miami",   date: "08/22/2018" }
  ],
  "Group 2": [
    { location: "Tampa",   date: "09/10/2018" }
  ]
};
```

Thx
jonpfl

Comment: Could you please make your question clearer, it is unclear what you are trying to achieve and could you please post your actual code

Comment: You've simply stated what you're trying to do. You haven't specified in what way we can help, especially since we can't see your code. Please show us that.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's summarize the description of your data in to actual code:

```
const dictionary = {
  "Group 1": [
    { location: "Orlando", date: "07/10/2018" },
    { location: "Miami",   date: "08/22/2018" }
  ],
  "Group 2": [
    { location: "Tampa",   date: "09/10/2018" }
  ]
};
```

Now, from the description of your desired UI, we can come up with the following viewmodel formats:

```
function App() {
  this.groups = [];     // A list of groups
}

function Group() {
  this.label = "";      // The name of the group of buttons
  this.buttons = [ ];   // A list of Button viewmodel instances
}

function Button() {
  this.label = "";      // The city name
  this.hoverText = "";  // The date
}
```

With which you can construct this view:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: groups">
  <div>
    <strong data-bind="text: label">
    <!-- ko foreach: buttons -->
      <button data-bind="text: label, attr: { title: hoverText }"></button>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, all there's left is to transform the data format in to the right structure of viewmodels. This is the hardest part, and can be done in many ways. The primary trick is looping over the object's keys. In the example below, I use `Object.keys(dictionary)` to access `["Group 1", "Group 2"]`.

```js
App.fromDictionary = function(dict) {
  // Loop over each group name
  const groups = Object.keys(dict)
    .map(label => {
      // Create a list of Buttons for each child
      const buttons = dict[label]
        .map(buttonData => new Button(buttonData.location, buttonData.date));
        
      // Return a viewmodel with the key as the label, and the list of buttons
      // inside
      return new Group(label, buttons);
    });
    
  // Return a new App with our new groups
  return new App(groups);
};

const dictionary = {
  "Group 1": [
    { location: "Orlando", date: "07/10/2018" },
    { location: "Miami",   date: "08/22/2018" }
  ],
  "Group 2": [
    { location: "Tampa",   date: "09/10/2018" }
  ]
};

ko.applyBindings(App.fromDictionary(dictionary));


function Group(label, buttons) {
  this.label = label || "";
  this.buttons = buttons || [];
}

function Button(label, hoverText) {
  this.label = label || "";
  this.hoverText = hoverText || "";
}

function App(groups) {
  this.groups = groups || [];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: groups">
  <div>
    <strong data-bind="text: label"></strong>
    <!-- ko foreach: buttons -->
      <button data-bind="text: label, attr: { title: hoverText }"></button>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
</div>
```